# Python - Django - Suma demasiado lenta de una lista

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

Tengo un proyecto Django relacionado con consumos energéticos, por medio del cual visualizo los consumos de un hogar durante un mes. Para obtener esa información, empleo el siguiente código:

```
consumos = Measurement.objects.filter(idhogar=hogar)
filtrados = consumos.values_list("coste",flat=True).filter(timestampfinal__gt=iniciomes,timestampfinal__lte=finalmes)
suma = sum(filtrados)
```

---

**Actualización 1 - El modelo Measurement**:

```
class Measurement(models.Model):
     measurementid = models.AutoField(db_column='MeasurementID', primary_key=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
     valor = models.FloatField(db_column='Valor', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
     coste = models.FloatField(db_column='Coste', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
     timestampinicio = models.BigIntegerField(db_column='timestampinicio', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
     timestampfinal = models.BigIntegerField(db_column='timestampfinal', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
     devicesetupid = models.ForeignKey(Devicesetup, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='DeviceSetupID', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
```

El caso es que obtengo una lista con una longitud de 9000 valores. Pero al sumar todos los valores de dicha lista, tarda entre 3 y 4 segundos. He probado a crear un script de Python que suma una lista de 9000 valores, y tarda muchísimo menos (0.000176 segundos)

```
array = range(9000)
inicio = datetime.datetime.now()
suma = sum(array)
print "Tiempo: \t{}".format(datetime.datetime.now()-inicio)
```

No entiendo la razón de esta gran diferencia de tiempo, ya que en el código de Django obtengo una lista desde la base de datos y no hago más cosnultas, por lo que debería calcular la suma mucho más rápido.

He probado a poner `Debug = False` porque he leído que de esta manera se reduce el tiempo, pero no ha funcionado.

¿Cuál puede ser la causa de este problema, si las listas tratadas tienen la misma longitud?

Comment: Seguramente sea el backend de datos que necesita optimización. Añade el modelo de datos para poder indicarte algo.

Comment: Modelo Measurement añadido.

Comment: ¿Por qué simplemente no haces un `aggregate` tal como dice la documentación [aquí](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/aggregation/#aggregation)?

Comment: Ya lo he probado, pero sigue tardando el mismo tiempo, 3-4 segundos.

Comment: Pero tal vez esté relacionado con el desempeño de tu consulta y no con la ejecución de la suma. Instala debug toolbar para verificar si efectivamente solo estás haciendo una consulta y de preferencia usa tu gestor de base de datos para estas operaciones usando `aggregate`  como comenta @GermanAlzate.

Comment: Creo que no puedes comparar 9000 datos que tu ingreses de prueba en python y sumarlos a 9000 datos de una base de datos para luego sumarlos, obviamente en python tardara mucho menos en sumar, pero teniendo en cuenta que los datos vienen de una base de datos y son procesados, todo esto toma su tiempo por lo que lo mas optimo es hacer las operaciones desde la base de datos, recuerda que esos 9000 datos vienen de algún lugar y hay que hacer muchos movimientos que si lo hicieras con unos datos dummy desde python.

Comment: El caso es que he comprobado cuánto tiempo tarda en ejecutarse cada sentencia, y he visto que los datos son obtenidos rápidamente desde la base de datos, y lo que tarda es la suma. No me lo explico, porque mirando la documentación de la operación [values_list](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#values-list) se supone que devuelve una lista, por lo que la suma de los valores de esa lista no debería tardar tanto tiempo, porque no se está accediendo a la base de datos.

Comment: Dos preguntas rápidas: ¿qué es `idhogar`? Y la pregunta más importante, ¿has comprobado que la suma que da es correcta?

Comment: `idhogar` lo he puesto para simular que se filtraban los consumos de un hogar en concreto (el filtrado se hace de forma diferente, pero lo he puesto así para simplificarlo). Y sí, he comprobado que la suma es correcta.

Comment: Cuando dices de `values_list` que ***se supone*** que devuelve una lista, en realidad no es así. Lo que devuelve es un `QuerySet` que se evalua *"perezosamente"*. Fuerza la conversión a lista antes de hacer la suma.

Comment: Muchas gracias @ChemaCortes, me he dado cuenta de el problema no es la suma, sino la obtención de datos.

Answer (score 1):

¿Has probado a utilizar una [Agregación](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/aggregation/)? Así haría el cálculo únicamente tu motor de base de datos.

```
from django.db.models import F, FloatField, Sum

consumos = Measurement.objects.filter(idhogar=hogar)
filtrados = consumos.filter(timestampfinal__range=[iniciomes, finalmes]).aggregate(Sum(F("coste"), output_field=FloatField()))
```

Además, si vas a utilizar la expresión __lt y __gt con el mismo campo, puedes utilizar [range](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#range), que queda mucho más legible :).

Aún así, de cara a cuando crezca el tamaño de tu tabla, deberías añadir un `db_index=True` en la columna `timestampfinal`.

¡Un saludo!

Comment: Sí, lo he probado, pero sigue tardando entre 3 y 4 segundos. Me he dado cuenta de que el problema no es la suma, sino la obtención de datos. Sin embargo, aunque sea el motor de la base de datos quien haga la suma, ¿hay alguna forma de realizar esa query de manera más rápida?

Comment: Se me hace rarísimo que tarde tanto en hacer un Sum con 9000 registros. Estoy probando a hacer lo mismo con una tabla que tiene 37000 y tarda en resolver la consulta y devolverme los datos 0.017s. ¿No será que el problema está en el filtrado por `timestampfinal` y el volumen de registros que tiene tu tabla Measurement? ¿Has probado a ponerlo como `db_index`?

Comment: El volumen de registros podría ser la causa, pero ¿qué problema podría dar el filtrado por `timestampfinal`? Probaré a ponerlo como `db_index`. Gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: Si el volumen de registros es muy grande, el filtrado por un campo que no es índice es costosísimo. Prueba y me dices :).

Comment: Hago uso de una base de datos que ya existía antes de empezar con el proyecto de Django, hice uso de `inspectdb` para importar los modelos. ¿Puedo utilizar `db_index` en este caso?

Comment: Necesitarías hacer una migración para el ALTER TABLE de la base de datos para añadir el índice. ¿Podrías hacerlo o no puedes tocar el modelo de datos?

Comment: ¿Funcionó @ikermdagirre?